# Can I add an additional outlet using an existing outlet that has no ground wire?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I am looking to add new receptacles (15A) behind my TV by running a 12/2 romex (20A circuit/breaker) from a nearby existing receptacles (15A). The problem is, the existing receptacle has no ground wire. House is old (1960s), I see the that the receptacle is grounded to the metal box (tested this by running a voltage meter touching the hot prong and the metal box).

After doing some research, I came across the possible solution of just getting 15A GCFI receptacles (over buying 2 prong receptacles) for the new outlet and only connecting the hot and neutral wires. This seems to be the "relatively safest" method without rewiring from the breaker.

Is this the best and easy option? Or are better ones out there (again, without having to rewire from the breaker)?

All suggestions are welcomed! thank you for your guys/gals time!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the existing receptacle's box please?

Comment: The reason to answer ThreePhaseEel's query is we might find a way to get ground after all.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel
Thank you for the responses. I have added links to the photos. Sorry not sure how to upload the photos directly, the max 2MB is very restricting.

Answer (score 2):

### There are ground wires there, they're just buried in the back

In your photos, I can see some bare copper wires in the back of the box. These are the ground wires you are looking for, and you'll need to get them pulled out as far as they can go, then nut them to a box grounding pigtail screwed to the box and to another pigtail that goes off to the receptacle.

Comment: Ty. Are you saying there should be a tail end to the copper wire if I pull on it? It looks like it comes into the box and then out.

Comment: @JamesL -- it should have a tail end, yes, it may be tucked into a splice of some sort somewhere

Comment: If the metal box is grounded by wire held to the box by a grounding clip, then the receptacle will be grounded when it is fastened to the box, if the receptacle is installed correctly, right?  Attaching grounding wire to the grounding screw on the receptacle is not necessary, right?

Comment: @jimstewart note that the drywall is proud of the junction box, and the receptacle will **and should** float above the box by the drywall ears.  As such the current path is threads and head contact.   You have the right idea,  but this is only allowed for switches, not receptacles.

Comment: Ah, I see where I am preaching to the choir :)

Comment: @Harper, the fact that the ears on receptacles have grooves to allow them to be broken off by bending them back and forth indicates to me that the mfgr intended for them to be broken off in certain circumstances. The ears are dual purpose. In ordinary high production installation they are used to support the receptacle on the finish wall surface, but if the box is back too far this leads to the very irritating springy receptacle.

Comment: @JimStewart it's also necessary when fitting in 4x4 domed box covers, or really almost any industrial surface mounting with steel boxes and covers.  My only issue is that breaking off drywall ears *when you are in fact installing on drywall* risks the receptacle submarining too deep into the wall, creating a fitment problem with the cover.

Comment: All receptacle boxes (plastic) in our house are set back too far (1/4" to 1/2"). When replacing a receptacle I leave the ears on and use plastic shims to support the receptacle hard against the box. If I were installing receptacles in grounded metal boxes, I'd break the ears off to insure that the ears would not prevent the receptacle tabs from firm contact with the box.

Comment: If box is back to far over 1/8 they make a plastic box extensions  Slang  splash guards. 1/2 inch way to far gap.

Comment: We are getting away from the OP's situation with metal boxes, but I will say that I have used the box extensions in some cases. There is a type of extension which is softer plastic and the ends fits inside the box. Carlon blue plastic extenders fit against the end of the box and must be cut to depth. This is some trouble to cut square. I just use the plastic shims commercially available

Answer (score 0):

The box is grounded ,but not correctly. See the push on ground clip on box.The rest are in the box. Need to splice them together.  If the rest of the house is the same, should be fixed. The gap around box should be 1/8 for code 312.4 ..They also make a insulation you can add over outlet,for drafts and heat loss.

Comment: Is a ground wire held to the outside of the metal box by the clip at the top?

Comment: @RobertMoody how loud are they?

Comment: Yes that is the grounding clip.

Comment: Can you provide a code reference for a required 1/8” gap around the box,

Comment: Code 312.4 1/8 gap around box.312.3 Boxes in wood frame to be flush to drywall.

Comment: BTW: Art. 312 is for *cabinets* as you'd find housing a loadcenter interior -- and that gap is 1/8" *maximum*.

Answer (score -1):

The correct installation of a receptacle in a grounded metal box is to break off all four ears leaving only the end tabs. If shimming is necessary to space the receptacle out, then the broken off ears are placed around the screws between the tabs and the box. This establishes an adequate and approved conducting path. Just the screws and threads would test OK but are not considered adequate for high currents.

**EDIT**
Note that any **paper screw keeper must be removed** on at least on one end. This allows one end tab to make face-to-face contact with the metal box.

Good quality receptacles have a paper screw keeper on only one end and it does not have to be removed. The tab on the other end has a metal wire keeper which allows the tab to make face-to-face contact with a metal box as the screw is tightened. If the box is too far back, then use the broken off ears as conducting shim washers.

**EDIT2**
Looks like the box is set back as much as the thickness of the drywall. If so the two ears will not shim it out far enough. You will have to get some more washers for shims. Alternatively you could use all fours ears on one end and plastic shims on the other end.

Alternatively, since you have a lot of space around the box you could leave the ears on and use a stack of metal  washers. You could also use pieces of metal bar stock or square tube stock and drill a hole for the screw.

Comment: That is a clever way of solving the hard metal -metal yoke contact a receptacle needs. However you cannot allow the receptacle to be low from the wall. If you do, the cover plate won't fit properly.

Comment: If this was emt could see doing that.I still would use a self grounding  outlet. And the paper that holds the screw has to be removed. As far as the ears never heard of removing the ears to add grounding. yes remove make outlet flush.

Comment: Good quality receptacles have the paper screw keeper on only one end and it does not have to be removed. The tab on the other end  has a metal wire keeper which allows the tab to make face-to-face contact with a metal box as the screw is tightened.

Comment: @Harper, this use of the ears is not an improvisation, but IIUC it is all part of the design by the mfgr. The ears have holes in them for the express purpose of their being usable as shims.  Boxes are supposed to be placed with the edge not more than 1/8" in from the finished wall and a pair of ears will shim it out to proper position.  That should not be hard to do, but I see so many boxes inset farther than that!